# How to write complex Group by clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to  fetch the users who are accessing websites in hourly report on a day.

tried with multiple options, could any body suggest to achieve this query

[image]

Expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UegIW.png)

Comment: what exactly you are facing the problem .can you post your tried query

Comment: Yes, can you put together a sample of data you would like to have returned from your query please?

Comment: Let we see your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
SELECT USERNAME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), STARTTIME,102) AS DDAY,  DATEPART(hh, STARTTIME) DHOUR,  COUNT(*) AS RC
FROM YOURTABLE
GROUP BY USERNAME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), STARTTIME,102), DATEPART(hh, STARTTIME)
```

Sample data:

```
USERNAME    STARTTIME
aaa 2017-06-26 01:00:00.000
aaa 2017-06-26 01:10:00.000
bbb 2017-06-26 02:00:00.000
aaa 2017-06-26 02:10:00.000
```

Output:

```
USERNAME    DDAY    DHOUR   RC
aaa 2017.06.26  1   2
aaa 2017.06.26  2   1
bbb 2017.06.26  2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select users according to the startTime field .

```
select DISTINCT(UserName) from YourTable 
where TO_DATE(startTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_DATE(sysdate , 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

this query will return for you all the users that entered to your site in the current day.

You should have a look on some SQL lessons , it's not that hard . Use uncle google my friend :) . You can have a look at the site : https://www.w3schools.com .

I hope that it will help you .